# None of the following candidates is responsible because of the receiver type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

Working on an android project everything  is working  fine until now.
Getting this error

***None of the following candidates is responsible because of the receiver type mismatch***.
It occurs on the id of my views.

The below is the code

```
override fun getView(postion: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val myView = View.inflate(con, R.layout.item, null)
        val Tanamo = this.lis[postion]
        myView.txt1.text = Tanamo.Title
        myView.txt2.text = Tanamo.Author


        myView.but!!.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)

        myView.but.setOnClickListener({

            if (playRadio) {
                playRadio = false
                medi!!.stop()
                myView.but!!.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)
            } else {
                playRadio = true
                medi = MediaPlayer()

                try {
                    medi!!.setDataSource(Tanamo.Url)
                    medi!!.prepare()
                    medi!!.start()
                    myView.but!!.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                }
            }


        })

        return myView

    }
```

Comment: Post full stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys.
Have solve the issue.
I added .view to the extension.

**Wrong**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item.*
```

**Correct**

```
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item.view.*
```

Comment: I was fighting this minor omission for a while now. Something so simple can cause lots of grief. (and I think you should mark this answer as correct)

Answer (score 0):

Just inflate your view using `LayoutInflater` instead of inflate from `View`.

Replace this line:

```
val myView = View.inflate(con, R.layout.item, null)
```

By:

```
val myView = LayoutInflater.from(con).inflate(R.layout.item, null)
```